# npm install that used to work now doesn't

Tags: node.js, npm

I’m having trouble installing a node.js app that I’ve been able to install ok twice in the past, about a year ago. The plantower package reads from a Plantower PMSxx03 sensor using a usb port and a special cable.

I have recent versions of node.js and npm like this:

```
$ node --version
v12.16.1

npm --version
6.14.2
```

the instructions here:

https://github.com/perfectworks/node-plantower

say do this:

```
npm install --save plantower
```

but when I do I get errors -

```
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404): https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/releases/download/4.0.7/serialport-v4.0.7-node-v72-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for serialport@4.0.7 and node@12.16.1 (node-v72 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

is the first and there are several others ending like this:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! serialport@4.0.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the serialport@4.0.7 install script.
```

I’ve omitted quite a lot more. It seems there’s a missing serialport binary, is that right? And can anyone tell me how to correct this?

Dave

Comment: i think the Plantower need to update according to the version of the Nodejs !!!

Comment: what is the usage of this module

Comment: According to your logs npm tries to install serialport v4.0.7, but according to the package.json of the plantower package it should install v8.0.7 and higher. v4.0.7 is very old and does not support node v12. that's the error you quoted. Did you really do a fresh install in a fresh project, or are there locked versions in the package.json of your project?

Comment: Saad - I'm in discussion with the developer so we'll see about the update

Comment: Deep - allows me to read air pollution levels from a Plantower PMS5003 particle sensor

Comment: anarchist912 - I was interrupted during configuration for several weeks and don't know. I'll go back and check, thank you. I've copied this thread to the developer.

Comment: anarchist912 - I looked on my box like this: locate package.json | grep plantower and got /home/dave/node_modules/plantower/package.json
which looks reasonable but is too long to post here. It requires, if I'm reading it right,  "serialport": "^8.0.7" but I don't see what I can do to satisfy this dependency

Comment: The developer replied saying the serialport dependency was updated to "the latest version. Please try the version 1.1.7 with `npm i plantower@1.1.7` " which I did and now get errors like `concentration_pm2.5_normal: NaN µg/m^3 ` but the NaN is not useful @anarchist912

Comment: Do you get the error during installation or running your application? If the latter, then it might be due to changes in the newer versions of the mentioned packages and you'll have to adapt your code.

Comment: no install errors, occurs when running the app, I'll talk to the dev, thanks.